# <ul> element going out of it's respective <div> bounds

Tags: html, css

A sub-element of div is going out of bounds when I am resizing the div.

I have tried adding padding to resizable and resizers divs.

All the actual code is contained here:
https://github.com/LudwigVonChesterfield/Totally-Accurate-Political-Simulator

Snippets that do not work seperately from that said code:

```
        <div id='div_player_chat' class='resizable' style='height: 200px; width: 400px; top: 60%; left: 60%'>
            <div class='resizers'>
                <div class='resizer top-left'></div>
                <div class='resizer top-right'></div>
                <div class='resizer bottom-left'></div>
                <div class='resizer bottom-right'></div>

                <div class="chat-wrapper">
                    <form id="player_chat-form">
                        <input id="player_chat" autocomplete="off" title="chat"/>
                        <button id="player_say">Say</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ul id="player_events"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.resizable {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.resizable .resizers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resizers {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}


.chat-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  height: 35px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.chat-wrapper form {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
}

.chat-wrapper form input {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.chat-wrapper form button {
  width: 80px;
}

#player_events {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#player_events li {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

I expected the `<ul>` to be resized accordingly to it's `<div>` and to never go out of it's bounds.

The result however is:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/401030271417188355/613621706745053184/unknown.png

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/489092762466254848/613618996977336320/2019-08-21_09-22-31.mp4

Comment: try to remove `overflow-y: scroll;` to `ul`

Comment: firstly, I do want it to be scrollable. secondly, it doesn't help.

Comment: can you show with image where does an `ul` is going out of `div`

Comment: there is an image, and a video that were uploaded to discord in the end of the topic head...

Comment: you can try with Jqyery. If required code please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you using `flex`. I have removed `height` specification from `ul` and instead gave it `flex-grow` property which will take up remaining space. hope this helps you

```css
.resizable {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.resizable .resizers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resizers {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.chat-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  height: 35px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.chat-wrapper form {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
}

.chat-wrapper form input {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.chat-wrapper form button {
  width: 80px;
}

#player_events {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 90%;*/
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#player_events li {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='div_player_chat' class='resizable' style='height: 200px; width: 400px; top: 60%; left: 60%'>
  <div class='resizers d-flex'>
    <div class='resizer top-left'></div>
    <div class='resizer top-right'></div>
    <div class='resizer bottom-left'></div>
    <div class='resizer bottom-right'></div>

    <div class="chat-wrapper">
      <form id="player_chat-form">
        <input id="player_chat" autocomplete="off" title="chat" />
        <button id="player_say">Say</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="player_events"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```